# Where does Salesforce store the currency full name?

Tags: visualforce, multi-currency

So I have scanned both the CurrencyType and DatedConversionRate tables but both of them store only the IsoCode only.

I need to display the full name for a currency (say **AUD - Australian Dollar** for IsoCode AUD).

If I use this:

```
<apex:column value="{!eachCur.isoCode}"/>
```

in Visualforce page **apex:column** Salesforce magically automatically does this for me (eachCur is a CurrencyType record).

But if I put the field inside a child **apex:outputLink** element like this:

```
<apex:column ><apex:outputLink value="anotherPage">{!eachCur.isoCode}</apex:outputLink></apex:column>
```

it will only output the IsoCode with a link and nothing else.

As it is my requirement to show a link as well as output the full currency name, I am stuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this field alias to your query and it wil convert the value to its output label for you:

```
SELECT ..., toLabel(IsoCode) IsoLabel FROM CurrencyType
```